# Added Elements to List<Tuple>

Tags: c#, .net

I have a List defined as the following:

```
List<Tuple<string, long, DateTime>> firefoxBookmarkPaths = new List<Tuple<string, long, DateTime>>();
```

However I'm having trouble adding to my list:

```
List<Tuple<string, long, DateTime>> firefoxBookmarkPaths = new List<Tuple<string, long, DateTime>>();

long fileSize = 0;
string bookmarkFile = null;
string directoryToCheck = null;
DateTime fileModifiedDate = DateTime.MinValue;

foreach (var dir in basePersistDirectories)
{
    directoryToCheck = dir + @"\C\Users" + @"\" + Environment.UserName + @"\" + @"AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles";
    if (Directory.Exists(directoryToCheck))
    {
        var subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(directoryToCheck);
        foreach (var directory in subDirectories)
        {
            bookmarkFile = directory + @"\places.sqlite";

            if (File.Exists(bookmarkFile))
            {
                fileSize = new FileInfo(bookmarkFile).Length;
                fileModifiedDate = new FileInfo(bookmarkFile).LastWriteTimeUtc;
            }
        }

        firefoxBookmarkPaths.Add(bookmarkFile, fileSize, fileModifiedDate);
    }
}
```

The line `firefoxBookmarkPaths.Add(bookmarkFile, fileSize, fileModifiedDate);` is throwing error "No overload for method 'Add' takes 3 arguments." How can I add elements to this list?

Comment: You'll need to add a new instance of the Tuple to your List - i.e. firefoxBookmarkPaths.Add(new Tuple<string, long, DateTime>>(bookmarkFile, fileSize, fileModifiedDate));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not calling .Add() with a tuple, you are calling .Add() with three parameters, which it has no overloaded method for (as the error message tells you). Instead, you'll need to do something like this:

```
firefoxBookmarkPaths.Add(Tuple.Create(bookmarkFile, fileSize, fileModifiedDate));
```

<s>Or, if you are using C# 7.0, you can use some syntactic sugar:</s>

```
firefoxBookmarkPaths.Add((bookmarkFile, fileSize, fileModifiedDate));
```

**Edit**

As pointed out in a comment below, this is not syntactic sugar, but a different type. Although if you are using C# 7.0, using the different type would also be good.

Comment: It's not sintax sugar, it's a different type called `ValueTuple`, which is a struct. `Tuple` on the other hand is a class. If OP changes to the second option, he must change all the code, including the list declaration.

Answer (score 2):

`List<T>Add` method requires a T value when you try to add something.
So your line should be

```
firefoxBookmarkPaths.Add(new Tuple<string, long, DateTime>
                     (bookmarkFile, fileSize, fileModifiedDate));
```